# Design templates in a class library at top scope

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, resources

I use a class library (WPF user control library) to host some user controls which other (C#-) applications in the project solution consume. I want these controls to use XAML ControlTemplates residing at the top scope of the class library. The ControlTemplates do not have to be consumed outside the class library.

Here a template declaration:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="TemplateImageButtonSmall">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="img" Source="/PSCommonUI;component/Images/Buttons/ButtonMinus_normal.png"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then I have a user control in the class library, containing:

```
<Button Height="57" Margin="10,0,6,5" Name="button3" Template="{StaticResource TemplateImageButtonSmall}" Width="82">
```

In an application, I can use the App.xaml file for defining the templates. However, in a class library I don't have this option.

I have searched the web and found some answers including the use of a generic.xaml file, ComponentResourceKey, merging resource files and other stuff I find exaggeratedly complicated.

Also I read that theme definitions (resources in general) shouldn't reside in a class library.

But if I need some themes ONLY in this class library for the there hosted controls, how is best practice then?

Thanks in advance,

Julian

Comment: Try rephrasing, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. E.g. host user controls in an assembly?

Comment: I think that having a non-English key is a bad practice - not all consumers will be able to type it. Besides, I am not sure if it even works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant, however, if you want child UIElements from a specific UIElement and below to use control templates, then you can define the templates in a resource dictionary and merge the dictionary into the top control that you want the dictionary to be visible to.

Edit:

The assembly just contains the classes and resources within it. It has no events of its own (e.g. OnApplicationLoaded).

A control's XAML can contain resources of its own (e.g. control templates) for consumption by itself and child controls and thus define default styling.

Your **application** can merge the resource dictionaries into any level of the tree (application, window, control, ...) and thus override defaults.

If you want the styling to be dynamic (overrable by importing resource dictionaries) then using the *DynamicResource* keyword your XAML. If your resource is defined in the same XAML and can not be overridden then use the *StaticResource* keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Add a resource dictionary to your class library and define your resources (templates) there.  It doesn't have to be generic.xaml.

Then in each user control or other .xaml file reference the resource dictionaries you require using Xaml similar to:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="... path to dictionary 1"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="... path to dictionary 2"/>        
            <ResourceDictionary Source="... etc"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can then use resource keys from the merged dictionaries.